# in c# can `as` operator throw an exception if method call is involved

Tags: c#, .net, exception, type-conversion

I'm analyzing results of static analyzer.

In c# language can `as` operator throw an exception, if a method call is involved? i.e. does `as` block out ALL exceptions?

```
string string_name = some_object.Deserialize(openstream) as string;
```

Comment: downvoters please explain in comments

Comment: Why are you asking this? Does this code throw an exception? Why do you think the method call is relevant?

Comment: i'm analyzing results of static analyzer

Comment: Show the output of the static analyzer, you are misinterpreting the result or you are encountering a bug in it.

Comment: The code is rather involved - I extracted the questionable part here

Comment: No, the entire question is questionable. Please read [ask], and try to read your question as someone who doesn't know what you are trying to do, and doesn't see what's on your screen. The cast using `as` will never throw, period. Include the analyzer output that makes you think so.

Comment: I cleanup my question

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with the `as`, it is complaining you are using a `int` instead of a `string` as the 2nd parameter of `abc.Replace("c", 1)`, you need it to be `abc.Replace("c", "1")`

Comment: I intentionally generated exception

Comment: The point of question was whether as operator blocks out ALL exceptions!

Comment: Edited to clarify on all exceptions

Comment: Are you confusing compiler errors with exceptions? It's still not clear to me what you're asking by saying _"does `as` block out other exceptions"_.

Answer (score 4):

No, at very worst `as` will return `null` if the cast cannot be made.

One of two things is likely

1. Your method call `Deserialize` is throwing the exception
2. Something tries to use the value of `string_name` and is getting a `NullReferenceException`

Answer (score 2):

It is not the `as` operator instead your method which threw exception.

try:

```
var valueFromMethod = some_object.Deserialize(openstream);
string string_name =  valueFromMethod  as string;
```

You will get the exception on first line.

`as` will return `null` if casting results in failure. It will not throw exception.